# Create a new data.table of percentages based off another data.table

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new data.table of percentages based on another data.table.
I thought about creating new columns and dividing them but I have gotten lost in the logic of how to do this. Basically I need to know what the percentage of subjects MEET at VISIT

datatable_1

```
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| Meet          | Subject    | Visit        | 
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 1             |   a        |   1          |  
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 1             |   a        |   2          |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 0             |   a        |   3          |  
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 1             |   b        |   1          |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 1             |   b        |   2          |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 1             |   b        |   3          | 
+---------------+------------+--------------+
```

This is what the new data.table should look like

datatable 2

```
+---------------+------------+
| Subject       | Percentage |          
+---------------+------------+
| a             | .66        |
+---------------+------------+
| b             | .100       |
+---------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Meet` values has only 1/0 values, you can take average of `Meet` values for each `Subject`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Percentage = mean(Meet)), Subject]

#   Subject Percentage
#1:       a      0.667
#2:       b      1.000
```

This can also be written in base R and `dplyr`

```
#Base R
aggregate(Meet~Subject, df, mean)

#dplyr
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Subject) %>%summarise(Percentage = mean(Meet))
```